# Avoid Spring controller to match static content

Tags: java, spring, controller, resources

In a SpringBoot application (v. 1.4.0), I have a controller with the following annotation:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{category}/{brand}/{article_id}", method = GET)
```

This mapping was problematic, because also the static resources like `/images/product/p123.jpg` were matching that controller, causing issues.

So, based on another answer, I added a filter like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{category:^(?!.*\(^)(/images|/js|/css)($)).*}/{brand}/{article_id}", method = GET)
```

which will ensure that the controller will not match the static resources. However, now all the static resources are not served, I see messages like:

```
2016-08-24 21:24:56.670  WARN 10562 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/images/product/p123.jpg] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-08-24 21:24:56.671  WARN 10562 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/images/product/p124.jpg] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

On horrible solution would be to have paths like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{category}/{brand}/{article_id}/", method = GET)
```

(note the `/` at the end of the uri), but I personally would avoid this!
Another is to change the uri adding a prefix, which I want to avoid as well.

Any solution so that the static resources are handled without being sent to the controllers? 
A code snippet would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I know you want to avoid a prefix, but to make it look more RESTful and easily distinguish the paths, how about: /categories/{category}/brands/{brand}/articles/{article_id}

Comment: It is a website, I want to make it semantic-full, I don't need to make it RESTful

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it suffices that you change your regex.

First, why do you use the `/` character if you already have in the URI?
Second, you have capturing groups, be aware that you must use non-capturing groups when building regex for the URI.

Try to change it like this:

```
":^(?:(?!^images$|^js$|^css$).)*$"
```

So the controller should be changed as follow:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{category:^(?:(?!^images$|^js$|^css$).)*$}/{brand}/{article_id}", method = GET)
```

This will ensure that you will not match static resources under `resources/css` and `resources/images` and `resources/js` (or wathever you have in the path for the static content.

As a side nore, for building regexes I always use [REGEX101](https://regex101.com/) that provides excellent explanations and validation on your regex. It also highlights capturing groups!

Comment: Did you try the proposed change?